# Python Matplotlib - Overriding Stylesheets by adding spines back in

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have produced a 3x3 subplot in matplotlib and am using the following style sheet for aesthetics:

```
plt.style.use('ggplot')
```

I like the stylesheet, however I want the left spine to show. The following code works for interacting with my 9 ax's, but it is not adding the spine back in (everything else is working).

```
for ax in axes:
  ax.set_xlim(0,100)
  ax.tick_params(axis=u'both', which=u'both',length=0)
  ax.set_xticklabels(['0%','20%','40%','60%','80%','100%'],rotation = 45, fontname="Arial", fontsize=9)
  ax.set_yticklabels(themes,fontname="Arial", fontsize=9)
  ax.spines['left'].set_visible(True)
```

Are stylesheets uneditable once they are imported? or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `ggplot` style the spines are still there, it's rather the `"axes.edgecolor"` [that is white](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/559925e3ec43a5cbe1697a4496482d38d8489f68/lib/matplotlib/mpl-data/stylelib/ggplot.mplstyle#L11).

So a solution can be to turn it black, and instead turn all but the left spine off.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rc = {"axes.spines.bottom" : False,
      "axes.spines.top"    : False,
      "axes.spines.right"  : False,
      "axes.edgecolor"     : "black"}
plt.style.use(("ggplot", rc))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry about the delay in responding, I didn't get the notification that you responded,. Works great!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the spines in this style there are not set invisible but adapted in color, so you could try e.g.

```
ax.spines['left'].set_color('k')
```

and if you miss the tick lines you could add

```
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(size=3)
```